# How to verify that the source of an HTTP request is a particular App and not a third party?

Tags: authentication

This questions does not pertain to a specific OS (iOS, Android, WP8), but is about programming in general.

I have an app on a mobile device, that requests information from my web server. I want to ensure that my server returns data only to MY app, and not to third party apps.

Here is what I have so far:
Solution: Have the app encrypt the requested data, and use a nonce and timestamp to prevent replay attacks. Connect to the server using HTTPS, to prevent eavesdropping on the returned data.
Problem: The encryption key used by the app will have to be stored in the app, which presents a problem itself, since it can be extracted from the app.

How have other people solved this problem?